# Objective-C libraries multiple inheritance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance, sfauthorizationpluginview

I'm extending the NameAndPassword example (https://github.com/skycocker/NameAndPassword) and I need to acces IOBluetooth methods in this implementation file: https://github.com/skycocker/NameAndPassword/blob/master/NameAndPasswordPlugin.m

The interface looks like this:

```
@interface EXNameAndPassword : SFAuthorizationPluginView
```

How  do I make it inherit from `CBCentralManagerDelegate` like in appdelegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
```

I need `EXNameAndPassword` to inherit both from SFAuthorizationPluginView and CBCentralManagerDelegate and stuff. I believe this is quite easy, I'm just an obj-c beginner. I read about composition but I can't get it to work.

What I have currently is

```
 @interface EXNameAndPassword : SFAuthorizationPluginView <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
```

but I keep getting warnings about properties non synthesized -- I didn't have to synthesize them in my project which didn't require `SFAuthorizationPluginView` inheritance, therefore I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: A point of clarification, Obj-C doesn't support multiple inheritance and can only inherit from one class (In your case EXNameAndPassword inherits from SFAuthorizationPluginView and AppDelegate from NSObject). What you are doing is declaring multiple protocols (protocols are not classes in Obj-C) that your class conforms to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem.

```
@interface EXNameAndPassword : SFAuthorizationPluginView <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
```

is perfectly fine, I just had to disable architectures other than x86_64 in build settings.

Source: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/198573-property-problem.html

Answer (score 2):

the "properties non synthesised" warning is related to properties defined in a protocol.

In a class @properties are automatically @synthesized in the implementation, but in a protocol, it is the conforming class's responsibility to synthesize, so add:

```
@synthesize protocolPropertyName = _protocolPropertyName;
```

in `EXNameAndPassword.m`

Comment: In the interface I have `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *connected;`, and in implementation `@synthesize connected = _connected;`. This way I get "Synthesized property 'connected' must either be named the same as a compatible instance variable or must explicitly name an instance variable"

Comment: i'm not too sure about that error but this question seems to suggest its related to 64 bit changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110245/error-building-32-bit-os-x-app